# Mosaicking of rasters after upgrading to ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, image-mosaic

I just updated my ArcGIS to version 10.1. When using ArcMap, I've not been able to perform mosaicking without getting an error when I use the "Mosaic" tool in Data Management Tools -> Raster -> Raster Dataset. The error does not tell me anything. When using "Mosaic To New Raster" I don't get an error, but it also does not create the mosaic.

I've checked Environments settings to see if there was a problem there, but they seem to be correct. I'm using elevation rasters for the mosaic. Is there something that I need to do since the upgrade in order to correct this problem?

Comment: This may or may not help  http://downloads.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/189810.1_SP1_Announcement.pdf  Search for the word "mosaic"

Comment: Looks like there are many issues with mosaics in ArcGIS 10.1 there are hopefully fixed in ArcGIS 10.1 SP1 - Announcement here http://downloads.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/189810.1_SP1_Announcement.pdf [PDF] - planned to be available in Mid October 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the good advice from Roy, try building a raster mosaic (or raster catalog) directly in your geodatabase.  Check out the helpful reference on [raster data models](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000000n000000).

To begin, in Arc catalog right click on your GDB and choose New > Mosaic Dataset...

[image]

Again, in Arc catalog right click on the newly created mosaic dataset and select "Add Rasters..."  The new window will allow you to add your rasters and set the environment.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this.  However, I get an error message that reads "This geodatabase is not supported. Please upgrade your geodatabase to 10.0 or higher".

Comment: I've never upgraded my geodatabase when I upgraded my ArcGIS before.  How do I go about doing that?  Thanks!

Comment: First off, make sure you are not using a personal GDB, which will have a .mdb extension.  Personal GDBs have pretty serious file size limitations, whereas file geodatabases (.gdb) can handle large rasters.

Comment: Aaron, I tried what you and Roy suggested, but the resulting raster did not leave me with the option of "Classified" under "Symbology".  I attempted to calculate a histogram, but am not sure if I did it right since I am not able to apply a layer file using the "Classified" option.  Is there some step that I missed.  Before, ArcGIS would give me the option of computing the histogram, and then just go off and do it (not so doing it this way).

Comment: On the resulting raster, I tried running (in the Arc Toolbox) Data Management -> Raster -> Raster Properties -> Calculate Statistics. Then when I tried to apply a layer file in "Symbology" and "Classified" I got the error message "This dataset does not have valid histogram required for classification method, run Calculate Statistics tool to generate histogram".

Comment: @Renee, I was able to replicate the problem you are encountering.  Try the following: 1) Right click on your new raster mosaic (i.e. with your raster datasets loaded) > Select "Enhance" > and select "Calculate Statistics..." 3) Bring the raster mosaic into the dataframe as a layer 4) In the table of contents, expand the raster mosaic (i.e. click the "+") and right click "image" 4) Select Properties > Symbology > Classified.  You should notice the Classified option now available.

Comment: Yes, perfect!  Thank you Aaron!  I'll have to write this down so that I don't forget how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Raster datasets are sort of the 9.3 way of doing things.  I'd consider creating a Mosaic Dataset.  You can add whichever rasters you want and they'll be stitched together.

Right click gdb -> New -> Mosaic Dataset

To add rasters, right click the empty Mosaic Dataset -> Add Rasters (make sure to calculate statistics, build overviews, etc in advanced settings)

For me, this last step of checking all the settings was the critical step: check all of the following: update cell size, update boudary, update overviews (this will grey out the previous two). AND under Advanced, check all of the following: build pyramids, calculate statistics, build thumbnails.